# Connection timed out issue

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mailgun

We are using **Mailgun HTTP API** to send email and Jersey jars to connect to mailgun API

Below is my code snippet:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();

cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
Client client = Client.create(cc);

String pwd = "key-xxx"
String server = "xxx";
String email_from = "xxx";
String emailAddresses = "xxx";
String subject = "Mailgun Notification";
String message1 = "This is a TEST Message";

client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api",pwd));

WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/"+server+"/messages");
FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
form.field("from", email_from); 
form.field("to", emailAddresses);
form.field("subject", subject);
form.field("html",message1);
webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class,form)
```

When we send email to 500 users in loop one by one then it does not throw any exception and send the emails within 23 seconds 
but if we repeat the same process for 1000 users then it throws below exception whilst sending to 927th user:

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Comment: Sounds like the server stops responding.  What do the logs on the server say happens?  Are there rate limits on the server?  Are you allowed to send 1000 emails in 30 seconds?  This sounds like a layer 3 rate limit kicking in, stopping all network traffic to your IP, resulting in timeout at your end.

Comment: Try to slow the operation by putting a delay every (let's say) 200 emails.

Comment: first of all thanks all for quick response, @Jim Garrison: the exception shown above was taken from logs, we don't set any timelimit for that but we are expecting that 1000 emails should be sent within 46 seconds as the same process sent 500 emails within 23 seconds without any issue...can you please elaborate more about 3 rate limit and tell me what we can do to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: thing is that if we put delay in our code then it will affect the performance :( and i think 1000 emails will be sent in minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: It's not clear if you're using your own SMTP server or a 3rd party service as the SMTP gateway.  If it's a 3d party then you have to ask them why their server stops responding, what rate limiting they have in effect, and what their service agreement is with you.  What do they allow in terms of emails/minute?  If it's your own SMTP server then you have to look at its logs (including any anti-Denial-Of-Service software installed) to see why it stops responding completely.

Comment: Thanks Jim. We are using 3rd party service and they provide two ways to use their service: using SMTP or using their Rest API service. We are using their Rest service. We had asked them why their server didn't respond, they told us that they can't find any connection issue into their logs and no other client is complaining the same...that's not satisfactory answer they had given that's why i raised it on stack overflow..any suggestion please?